# Unable to extract data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a list of servers from this sample.

https://pastebin.com/eHGwhVmz

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open('html.txt', 'r') as html:
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', class_='grid_8')
    for tag in div:
        tag = div.find_all('td', class_='StatTDLabel')[2].text
        print(tag)
```

I can get the first server in the list, but I'm unable to iterate over them. When I try to use for loop i get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

sample_html = """The contents of your pastebin"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser").find_all("tr")
servers = [
    [i.getText(strip=True) for i in row.find_all("td")] for row in soup[1:]
]
print(tabulate(servers, headers=["Country", "Location", "Address", "Status"]))
```

Output:

```
Country    Location      Address               Status
---------  ------------  --------------------  -------------
ZA         Johannesburg  jnb-c17.ipvanish.com  15 % capacity
ZA         Johannesburg  jnb-c18.ipvanish.com  15 % capacity
ZA         Johannesburg  jnb-c19.ipvanish.com  31 % capacity
ZA         Johannesburg  jnb-c20.ipvanish.com  12 % capacity
ZA         Johannesburg  jnb-c21.ipvanish.com  9 % capacity
ZA         Johannesburg  jnb-c22.ipvanish.com  10 % capacity
AL         Tirana        tia-c02.ipvanish.com  17 % capacity
AL         Tirana        tia-c03.ipvanish.com  23 % capacity
AL         Tirana        tia-c04.ipvanish.com  19 % capacity
AL         Tirana        tia-c05.ipvanish.com  15 % capacity
AE         Dubai         dxb-c01.ipvanish.com  30 % capacity
AE         Dubai         dxb-c02.ipvanish.com  26 % capacity
```

To get the server addresses only, pick the third column, which has index of `2`.

For example:

```py
servers = [
    [i.getText(strip=True) for i in row.find_all("td")][2] for row in soup[1:]
]
print("\n".join(servers))
```

Output:

```
jnb-c17.ipvanish.com
jnb-c18.ipvanish.com
jnb-c19.ipvanish.com
jnb-c20.ipvanish.com
jnb-c21.ipvanish.com
jnb-c22.ipvanish.com
tia-c02.ipvanish.com
tia-c03.ipvanish.com
tia-c04.ipvanish.com
tia-c05.ipvanish.com
dxb-c01.ipvanish.com
dxb-c02.ipvanish.com
```

Comment: Yes but only the addresses

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open('html.txt', 'r') as html:
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = div.find_all('td', class_='StatTDLabel')
    for tag in tags:
        tagtext = tag.find(text=True, recursive=False) #take only immediate text of the element and ignore child element texts
        if tagtext:
            print(tagtext)
```